# ImageMagick -monitor command for animated gif resizing

Tags: imagemagick, progress-bar, image-resizing

Using ubuntu:

```
convert /home/cms/img2.gif -monitor -resize 150x /home/cms/result.gif
```

I'm using ImageMagick for resizing/cropping purposes and want to create progress bar for resizing procedure. Everything is ok for jpeg images, but when i'm trying to resize large animated gif it's creating TONS of various information about % complete.

I'm confused. I have tried to follow overall progress, by reading 200mb+ log...

Log says that resizing is 100%, but after that, there is about 200mb others operations like Dither, Reduce, Saving etc...

**Is there a easier way to follow progress of animated gifs resizing?**

**What is the strict order of operations ImageMagick is doing, when processing animated gif?**

Thanks.